# React Hooks - Set state based on multiple async calls in loop

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks

My below effect is trying to accomplish the following:

1. I need to make 3 concurrent XHR requests for jobs, postings, and sale items.
2. When the data returns, I need to sort the records into open, closed, and 'therest' arrays which I then append to a 'running_total' array.
3. Once all of the XHR requests have been completed and sorted, I want set the running_total array to state.

Unfortunately, my below code does not seem to respect async / await and once the effect has finished running, I end up with an empty array. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const types = ["jobs", "postings", "sale_items"];

    async function getEntityReferencesAsync() {
      let running_total = [];
      types.forEach(
        function(type) {
          let open = [];
          let closed = [];
          let therest = [];

          const request = await get_data(
            `https://myapi.com.com/${type}/${props.id}`
          );

          response.then(
            function(result) {
              const result_array = result.data.records;
              result_array.forEach(
                function(item) {
                  item["type"] = type;
                  if (item.status === "open") {
                    open.push(item);
                  } else if (item.status === "closed") {
                    closed.push(item);
                  } else {
                    therest.push(item);
                  }
                }.bind(this)
              );

              running_total = [
                ...running_total,
                ...open,
                ...closed,
                ...therest
              ];
            }.bind(this)
          );
        }.bind(this)
      );
      return running_total;
    }

    async function getSortedData() {
      const sorted_array = await getEntityReferencesAsync();
      setEntityReferencesData(sorted_array);
    }

    getSortedData();
  }, [props.id]);
```

FYI my get_data function looks like:

```
async function get_data (endpoint, params) {
    if (params === null) {
        return await axios.get(endpoint)
    } else{
        return await axios.get(endpoint, {params: params});
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you considered mapping your `types` array into promises and using `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`? I also see a lot of `bind` being used when that isn't necessary. Your async/await functions are being respected, but it seems that you are struggling to realize that all `async` functions return a `Promise`. For example `getSortedData();` near the end of your `useEffect` will return a `Promise` and not a resolved value (although in this case it will just resolve to `undefined`).

Comment: Thank you @spex. I was not aware of Promise.all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled